# Upsert with children entity in Microsoft CRM Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am calling an Upsert request on an entity using Microsoft's SDK for their Dynamics 365 CRM. This Upsert call also includes child entities, in this case, it is a sales order and a product on that sales order. When I initially called the Upsert it works fine, when I update something it works fine. But if I add an additional product and try to add that through an Upsert on the order entity it fails saying it can't find the product on the existing order. Is this intended behavior? Do I need to call separate add and delete requests for each added or removed line?

Here is a snippet of the code:

```
        //create order entity
        var so = new CRMSalesOrder();
        //create product entity for each product
        var sod = new CRMSalesOrderDetail();
        so.Order_Details.Add(sod);
        //create the upsert request
        multipleRequest.Settings.ReturnResponses = true;
        var upsertRequest = new UpsertRequest()
        {
            Target = so,
            RequestId = Guid.NewGuid()
        };
        multipleRequest.Requests.Add(upsertRequest);
        batchResponse = (ExecuteMultipleResponse)service.Execute(multipleRequest);
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Never tried a combination of UpsertRequest and related entities. I know it's possible to create parent records with their children in one call - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg309282(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN If it fails for you I believe that Upsert message can't process it cause it was not designed to support this scenario.